# Does R predict or forecast on an arimax model?

Tags: r, time-series

I have some data which i am trying to work on. I am pretty new to R though, but i love R. First, I fit an `arima` model to this data and used the `detectIO` function in R to detect a single influential outlier (IO). I then incorporated this IO into my model and then developed an `arimax` model, now with the IO. 
I first used this model:

```r
Model2 = arimax(mydata, order=c(0,2,1),
                seasonal=list(order=c(0,0,1), period=12), io=c(48))
```

Then later, used the model below after seeing a similar code in a book:

```r
Model4 = arima(mydata, order = c(0, 2, 1),
               seasonal=list(order = c(0, 0, 1), period = 12), 
               xtransf=data.frame(I48=1*(seq(mydata)==48), I48=1*(seq(mydata)==48)), 
               transfer=list(c(0,0), c(1,0)))
```

I then run the `predict` function on these two models and I keep getting this error:

```r
> predict(Model4, n.ahead=24)

Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  :
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I don't know if I am using the right functions and codes? Does there really exist a `predict` function on `arimax`?

I would also appreciate if I get any help on how to set-up the `xtransf` with some real data values.

Comment: you should include your predict code in your question.  if that's where the error is coming from, it'd help to be able to see your code.

Comment: please format your code as `code` by selecting all code areas and pressing Ctrl+K

Comment: @ClarkW.Griswold: my predict code was: predict(Model4, n.ahead=24)

Comment: @wnstnsmth: thanks for the nice editing work. but how will i do that with the mac os?

Comment: I didn't do the editing, someone else did, but on Mac it should be Cmd+K

Comment: @wnstnsmth: I had already tried with cmd+K but did work though. but   thanks anyways.

Comment: I've put the predict() code into the question - more likely to be seen there than in the comments.  BTW you can also use the clickable icons to format a selected part of your question or answer as code.

Comment: Tente fitted.Arima(mod). Boa sorte.

Comment: Try fitted.Arima (mod). Good luck. Hélio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about arimax. Your second example, using arima, could be:

```
foo <- arima (mydata, order=c(0, 2, 1), seasonal=list (order=c(0, 0, 1), period=12), 
    xreg=as.numeric (seq (mydata) == 48))

predict (foo, 10, newxreg=0)
```

Not sure if I got it right, but hopefully that will put you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for looking. It really helped and my predict-code is working now. I did not detect any more outlier after incorporating this model. thanks a lot.  But could you explain to me a little bit more about the xreg function used and the newreg=0 function. I have been seeing the xreg function but i thought it is only used on an additive outlier. @Wayne

Comment: @ Wayne: thanks. could you check the post just right above this. thanks

Comment: xreg is used to specify covariates and in this case I specified an anomaly indicator, which is additive. The newxreg is used in the predict to specify new values of the variable you put into xreg -- you have to supply all variables for the prediction that you did for the original.

Comment: @b2amen if you found the answer useful can you select the tick next to it to indicate your question is resolved? thanks.

Comment: @PeterEllis: thanks a lot. I have done exactly that.

Comment: @Wayne: I just noticed this after running my code:

Comment: @Wayne:summary(foo) produces "training set error measures". what could that be? 
ARIMA(0,2,1)(0,0,1)[12]                    

Coefficients:
          ma1     sma1     xreg
      -0.6808  -0.4223  -0.1105
s.e.   0.0913   0.1877   0.0909

sigma^2 estimated as 0.02513:  log likelihood=28.11
AIC=-50.21   AICc=-49.6   BIC=-41.22

Training set error measures:
Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : 
  dims [product 113] do not match the length of object [0]
In addition: Warning message:
In .cbind.ts(list(e1, e2), c(deparse(substitute(e1))[1L], deparse(substitute(e2))[1L]),  :
  non-intersecting series

Comment: @Wayne: i'm not sure if you would be able to read the above. I just don't know how to edit. sorry

Comment: @b2amen: Is this an error you get from `arima` or `predict`? What are you using for `xreg`? I've never seen this error before.

Comment: @Wayne: summary(foo) gives me the coefficients for ma1, sma1 xreg but with this error "training set error measures". But the predict(foo) works perfect.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `predict()` method for `arimax` models. Strange but true. The author of `TSA` has written functions that enable you to fit a transfer model, but not use it for forecasting.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob. Okay! But could you help me set-up an arima model  then, that I could use for prediction                                                                    Model2 = arima(mydata, order=c(0,2,1),
                seasonal=list(order=c(0,0,1), period=12))           This is a model i first used. Then i used the detectIO(Model2) function to detect an I0=48. Could you help me set  up an arima model with an incorporated IO=48, that i could use for prediction or forecasting.

Comment: @Wayne has already done that for you.

Comment: thanks. Wayne really helped and I appreciate. I just thought you had some other ideas which might differ. Thanks anyways

Comment: The only other suggestion I have is to use Arima and forecast from the forecast package in place of arima and predict from the stats package.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob. I appreciate. You are really awesome. Your data site is really helpful too.

Comment: @RobHyndman, is there any chance that the forecast package will have functions built for transfer functions (fitting and forecasting)?

Comment: I'd say the chance was positive, but relatively small unless someone else offers to write the code.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the "predict" function can be applied if the arimax function is given an already differenciated time series (in case of non stationary data) or as it is in case of stationary data. Basically when both the order d and D are set to 0. Hope it helps.